# How can I get two block elements to stay on the same line?

Tags: css

I have two span elements that I would like to stay on the same line. In FF and other browsers, my code works fine but in IE6 it breaks. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<span style="font-family:Arial;text-align:left;font-size:30px;color:#06a;">
  test
</span>
<span style="font-family:Arial;float:right;font-size:12px;color:#06a;text-align:left;">
  This is the line that jumps down and needs to be brought level with the above span element.
</span>
```

Comment: Use "External style sheet" or "Internal style sheet" to make your text more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use "float:left" on the first span.

Comment: Anything to ease another csser's pain!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note: span, by default, isn't block-level.

Most bugs in IE6's CSS rendering have well-known workarounds and have been well documented [here](http://www.positioniseverything.net).

As an aside - is IE6 support really important to your site?  IE6 use has been dropping sharply lately, and many sites are dropping support for it.

Answer (score 0):

The block using float:right should be first in HTML

Answer (score 0):

test
This is the line that jumps down and needs to be brought level with the above span element.

just add  float:left; the first span